# How to prevent text overflow in card component in Ant design

Tags: javascript, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using the card component to design a card with image and a title and description

```
<div>
            <Card
                hoverable
                style={{ width: 700, wordWrap: 'break-word'}}
                cover={<img alt="example" src={ urlToImage } />}
            >
                <Meta title={ title } description={ content } />
            </Card>
        </div>
```

The problem is that since the length of title is large it seems to do a text overflow on the same.
I tried adding a custom JSX to the title component but it does not allow styling for some reason

Link to the sand box [SandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-snowflake-r73mi)

Answer (score 1):

```
.ant-card-meta-title {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Could change the css. It uses a class `.ant-card-meta-title`. In css file add

```
.ant-card-meta-title {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```